# Using https for REST requests from inside expressjs applicaiton

Tags: node.js, express

From inside my expressJS application I have to verify that a cookie token is valid with a back-end server.   So the relevant code involved in this is as follows:

```js
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('GET: ' + req.path);
    
    // ...

    const payload = JSON.stringify({ authnToken: token });
    const opts = { ... authServerOptions };
    opts.headers['Content-Length'] = payload.length;

    // build request

    const restReq = https.request(authServerOptions, result => {
      console.log('back-end response' + result.statusCode);

      result.on('data', data => {
        next();    // token is good now proceed.
      });

      result.on('error', error => {
        res.redirect('somewhere');  // token is bad or timeout
      });

    });

    restReq.write(token);
    restReq.end();
  }
```

So the main `get` function sets the REST request in motion and then just returns without calling `next()` or anything.

Questions:

- Is this the right code for doing this?  What happens if the callbacks are never called?
- Is the application blocked from processing other requests until the back-end server returns or times out?
- If so is there some way of freeing up the thread to process more requests?

Thanks in advance for any help.  I haven't found many examples for this code pattern so if there is one a link would be appreciated.

Comment: [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is much easier to use. Node will continue running other javascript while it waits for the network io to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think the general idea of your implementation is correct.

I would also suggest, as done in the comments, to use a client such as axios to handle the request in a less verbose and more comprehensive manner, which would leave your code looking something like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const payload = JSON.stringify({ authnToken: token });
  const opts = { ... authServerOptions };
  opts.headers['Content-Length'] = payload.length;
  axios.post(url, payload, opts)
    .then(response => next())
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      res.redirect('somewhere');
    });
});
```

A bit more to the point, but functionally almost equivalent to your implementation. The one thing you are missing is the onerror callback for your request object, which currently may fail and never return a response as you correctly suspected. You should add:

```js
restReq.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error);
  res.redirect('somewhere');
});
```

On the same vein, it would probably be more fitting to call `next` on result `end`, instead of doing so while reading response data:

```js
result.on('end', () => {
  next();
});
```

Then you'd be covered to guarantee that a callback would be invoked.

Neither implementation blocks the processing of future requests, as the call to the token validation service is done asynchronously in both cases.